# How to edit (insert new fields into) IDA structures?

Tags: ida, hexrays

I'm trying to reverse a bigger structure used in an old game. Obviously I didn't know all fields when I created the structure type, and now I want to edit in some new fields / change pure byte gaps into meaningful fields.

This, for example, is a structure of a GuiButton which I know by now, but it's just a gap yet:
[image]

I don't find any way to edit the field of the structure. Do I have to completely delete the existing structure and create a new one?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can undefine the field (select **Undefine** from the context menu or press <kbd>U</kbd>) and then press <kbd>D</kbd> to define a new field in the gap.

Answer (score 2):

Position cursor where you want to insert (cannot be at the structure end) and
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>  (see expand command in IDA documentation).

Comment: Is this a new feature, by the way? My question is from 2016, and if I recall correctly, Ctrl+E always _appended_ bytes even if the cursor was in the middle of the struct. But I may have just been blind back then.